# Firebase returning array with null and some object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAGHEgm48s7_QkBwLw0UX-yCBLQg06zvdA",
  authDomain: "fir-bef76.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://fir-bef76.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "fir-bef76.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "207871344593"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var ref = firebase.database().ref("employeeAttendace")
  .child("427188EI/2017/1");

ref.once("value").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.5/firebase.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I am storing My Data in firebase. But While fetching data i am getting Array filled with null, and object Instead of JSON object.

---

```
   JSON Structure:
    employeeAttendance
      -4114EI
        -2017
          -1
             -1:{Key:value}
             -2:{Key:Value}
             -3:{Key:Value}
             -4:{Key:Value}
             -5:{Key:Value}
```

**firebase fetching code :**

```
    var ref=firebase.database().ref("employeeAttendance/4114EI/2017/1");
ref.once("value",function(data){


  //Here i am getting 
[null,null,{key,value},{key,value},{key,value}]
        });
```

Please help me how to solve null value problem

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dawBf.png)

[Output Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDVcw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got solution.Actually JSON structure was not well form as per the firebase rule.